# Detecting doubleTap in PhaserJS

Tags: phaser-framework

I am a complete newbie in PhaserJS. I am trying to develop a game in PhaserJS where tapping the screen once should make the user avatar move on the screen and double-tapping should make it jump. However, I am not being able to figure out how to catch the double tap event. I have seen this [tutorial](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/on-tap) in their official documentation, but that didn't work. When I am putting this line

```
game.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);
```

in the

```
function create(){
    .....
}
```

function, it is showing this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

I am being able to detect single tap events using this code:

```
if(game.input.onTap && player.body.touching.down){
    player.setVelocity(-530);
}
```

I've read another thread where the members have commented that to detect double click, one should start a timer and check both the clicks are coming within a threshold value. However, I think this is not a fool-proof method and there must be a better way of doing it. Can anyone please help?

Edit:
Relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 800;
var height = 600;

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y:300 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload (){
    this.load.image("sky", "{% static 'task_scheduler/assets/sky.png' %}");
    this.load.image("ground", "{% static 'task_scheduler/assets/platform.png' %}");
    this.load.image("star", "{% static 'task_scheduler/assets/star.png' %}");
    this.load.image("bomb", "{% static 'task_scheduler/assets/bomb.png' %}");
    this.load.spritesheet("dude", "{% static 'task_scheduler/assets/dude.png' %}", {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48});
}

var platforms;
var player;
var cursors;
var stars;
var bombs;
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function create (){
    //some other code here

    //mouse and touch
    this.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);
}

function onTap(pointer, doubleTap){
    if (doubleTap){
        player.setVelocityY(-530);
    }else{
        player.setVelocityX(160);
        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full js file or at least the relevant part?

Comment: @ChrisGhenea Added the code. Currently, the js is embedded in html file only.

Answer (score 1):

```
function create (){
    //some other code here

    //mouse and touch
    this.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);
}
```

Here you should use `game.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);`
because `this` would reference to context from which `create` function is called. So, `this` wouldn't have property `add` and other properties that are available with `game` variable.

As far as the Double Tap is concerned that would be detected by phaser. I don't think you need to write any explicit code for that. `onTap` function would work just fine.